# Automatic restart android mono app on crash

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I have question regarding the option to automatically restart an android based app if an uncaught exception is fired causing the application to quit.  My idea for implementing this request is as follows,

1. Create a PendingIntent in the OnCreate function of the MainLauncher.   Would this PendingIntent point to a BroadCastReceiver in this case which could then fire off the MainLauncher Activity to restart the app?

   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    restartIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, typeof(aBroadcastReceiverMaybe)), 0);
    }
2. Catch any uncaught exceptions for my app.  My understanding is you could possibly override a function Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() but this is in Java implementation for android.  I am not quite sure how this works in under the xamarin framework
3. In the uncaught exception override, create an AlarmManager which will fire the PendingIntent from step 1 after 4 seconds.  Force quit the app using an exit() function, again unsure of implementation under xamarin framework.
4. After 4 second delay in step 3, BroadcastReceiver will be notified.  On Receiving notice, fire up MainLauncher Activity to restart app.

If there is a more suitable implementation for this task I would be happy to take onboard.  Look forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better off handling the errors mate. As a user if I have a buggy app on my phone and every time it crashes it automatically restarts it is only gonna become an annoyance.

Comment: Sometimes it is impossible to handle all the exceptions. I have developed an XF application that is used on dedicated device in an industrial setting, and I had implemented the auto-restart functionality for unhandled exceptions. The unhandled exception are typically some kind of "cannot access a disposed object" exception that is deep inside XF and that is impossible to reproduce in a test setting. In fact I am using a separate application that is responsible for launching and restarting the main application. But I do agree that this is not the preferred way for consumer applications.

Comment: What about unattended applications? Not everyone is building apps for the app store.

Comment: @TidyDev sure, there could be use cases where your intention for an Android app is to restart without any user intervention. For this, I believe nowadays there are ways where you can tell the OS to run one and only one application. In such scenarios, I believe the OS restarts the application if it crashes.